# How do you encode hashtag in RedirectToAction

Tags: model-view-controller, encode, redirecttoaction

I want to redirect to a specific tab:

```
RedirectToAction("Index/#requests")
```

But it gets translated to /%23requests. I checked it out with

```
RedirectToAction("Index", new { tab = "#requests" })
```

but it still gets the %23 for the #.

How do I make the hashtag appear on the url?

Comment: forgot to mention that  System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("#requests") didnt work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '#' sign has a special meaning so it's normal to be url encoded. The desired result can be accomplished by using the `Redirect` method with string literal for url or some combination of `Url.Action` and `Redirect`.

```
var url = Url.Action("Index") + "#requests";
return Redirect(url);
```